# Streamlines, streaklines, and pathlines

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, multivariable-calculus, vector-fields

I still have difficulty distinguishing the streamlines, streaklines and pathlines of a vector fields. Can you help me to understand this concepts by explaining to me the difference between them?

---

By example, consider the following vector fields
$$
\vec{V}(x,y,z) := \omega x \: \vec{\textbf{i}} + \omega y \: \vec{\textbf{j}} + \left( -\omega x + \alpha t \right) \: \vec{\textbf{k}}
$$
where $\alpha$ is a constant and the parameter $\omega \ne 0$.

(a) Calculate the pathline of the particule at $(x_0, y_0, z_0)$ when $t=0$.

(b) Calculate the streamline passing by the point $(x_0, y_0, z_0)$.

(c) Calculate the streaklines of passing by the point $(x_0, y_0, z_0)$.

Comment: I have to say that the explanation at Wikipedia (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Streamlines,_streaklines,_and_pathlines) seems pretty clear, both from the conceptual and from the mathematical point of view.

Comment: Maybe, but I don't understand how to apply that in this example.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since the vector field is time dependent, the pathline, streamline and streaklines are different concepts, see [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Streamlines,_streaklines,_and_pathlines). Note that these notions are frame dependent.

The *pathline* is the actual path in space followed by a particle which is moved by the flow of the vector field. The trajectory of the particle as a function of time, $(x_p(t),y_p(t),z_p(t))$, therefore obeys the dynamical system
\begin{align}
 \frac{\text{d} x_p}{\text{d} t} &= \omega\,x_p, \\
 \frac{\text{d} y_p}{\text{d} t} &= \omega\,y_p, \\
 \frac{\text{d} z_p}{\text{d} t} &= -\omega\,x_p +\alpha t,
\end{align}
with initial condition $(x_p(0),y_p(0),z_p(0)) = (x_0,y_0,z_0)$. Solving this system should be no problem.

A *streamline* is a curve which exists in its entirety for every time $t$, but changes with time. To calculate a streamline, we first fix time $t = t_*$. A streamline is a contour of the fixed velocity field. Such a contour line is everywhere tangent to this fixed vector field. To find a parametric representation for such a streamline, denoted by $(x_s(\sigma),y_s(\sigma),z_s(\sigma))$, the fact that the streamline is everywhere tangent to the fixed vector field means that
\begin{align}
 \frac{\text{d} x_s}{\text{d} \sigma} &= \omega\,x_s, \\
 \frac{\text{d} y_s}{\text{d} \sigma} &= \omega\,y_s, \\
 \frac{\text{d} z_s}{\text{d} \sigma} &= -\omega\,x_s +\alpha t_*.
\end{align}
We can fix our parametrisation by choosing $(x_s(0),y_s(0),z_s(0)) = (x_0,y_0,z_0)$. You can solve this dynamical system, where the parameter $\sigma$ plays the role of the 'time variable', and obtain the requested stream line.

The *streakline* is the most difficult one to calculate. The line itself changes in time, and is determined by the *entire history* of both the path and the time dependent vector field. You can view it as a collection of end points of path lines of particles released in the flow between time $0$ and time $t$. The first particle to be released has traced out our previously calculated path line, and the last particle to be released is still at the initial point $(x_0,y_0,z_0)$. Therefore, the end points of the path line and streakline coincide.

Suppose that at some earlier time $\tau$ (so $0<\tau<t$), a particle was released at $(x_0,y_0,z_0)$. This particle follows the flow of the vector field until time $t$. Let's parametrise the path of this particle with the parameter $\theta$, such that the curve $(x_\tau(\theta),y_\tau(\theta),z_\tau(\theta))$ is always tangent to the vector field. That means that this curve obeys the dynamical system
\begin{align}
 \frac{\text{d} x_\tau}{\text{d} \theta} &= \omega\,x_\tau, \\
 \frac{\text{d} y_\tau}{\text{d} \theta} &= \omega\,y_\tau, \\
 \frac{\text{d} z_\tau}{\text{d} \theta} &= -\omega\,x_\tau +\alpha (\tau + \theta).
\end{align}
Here, we fixed the parametrisation such that at $\theta = 0$, the particle starts at $(x_0,y_0,z_0)$; at that moment (so at time $\tau$), the vector field is given by $(\omega x_0,\omega y_0, -\omega x_0 + \alpha \tau)$. We've chosen $\theta$ such that it increases the same way the global time increases. You could view $\theta$ as 'the particle's own time'. Anyway, remember that we're only interested at the end point of the path of this particle which was released at time $\tau$. That is, we're interested in $(x_\tau(t),y_\tau(t),z_\tau(t))$ (note that you can find the parametrised path $(x_\tau(\theta),y_\tau(\theta),z_\tau(\theta))$ by solving the associated dynamical system). The collection of all these end points for all intermediate times $\tau$ (for which $0<\tau<t$) is the streakline we're after. So, the streakline at time $t$, parametrised by $\tau$, is given by $(x_\tau(t),y_\tau(t),z_\tau(t))$.

Comment: amazing explanation! thank you :)