# Plotting the streaklines knowing the pathlines

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, multivariable-calculus, vector-fields, fluid-dynamics, runge-kutta-methods

I have a two-dimensional velocity field $$\mathbf{V}=\begin{pmatrix}
u \\
v
\end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix}
0.5+0.8x \\
1.5+2.5\sin(\omega t)-0.8y
\end{pmatrix}$$ from Example 4-5 in "Fluid Mechanics: Fundamentals and Applications" 2nd Edition.

I have correctly derived the **streamlines** from $$\frac{dy}{dx}=\frac{v}{u}$$ at $t=2$ giving $$y=\frac{C}{0.8(0.5+0.8x)}+1.875$$ in agreement with the text.

Using a Runge-Kutta numerical integration method I approximated the **pathlines** from $0<t<2$ s using these equations. $$u=\frac{dx}{dt}=0.5+0.8x$$ $$v=\frac{dy}{dt}=1.5+2.5\sin(\omega t)-0.8y$$ Plotting the equations agrees with the figure in the text. My results are on the left

- red: starting from $(0.5,0.5)$
- blue: starting from $(0.5,2.5)$
- green: starting from $(0.5,4.5)$

and the light pink curves in the right figure are from the text.

[image]

These questions ([here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12931172/plotting-pathlines-streaklines-given-velocity-vector-field?answertab=scoredesc#tab-top), and [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1721952/streamlines-streaklines-and-pathlines)) deal with methods to find the **streaklines**. This [link](http://pillars.che.pitt.edu/student/slide.cgi?course_id=10&slide_id=9.0), however, has been the most helpful in understanding how to derive the necessary equations. But my results do not agree with the text. The text defines the method for plotting the **streaklines** this way.

> Finally, the streaklines are simulated by following the paths of *many* fluid tracer particles released at the given three locations at times between $t=0$ s and $t=2$ s, and connecting the locus of their positions at $t=2$ s.

I want to try and avoid solving the ODEs by hand since $y(t)$ will involve an integrating factor, but more importantly, to arrive at equations for $x=x(x',t,t')$ and $y=y(y',t,t')$ without going through lots of error-prone algebra.

From the third link above $(x',y')$ are the future positions of the particle at time $t'$ and $t$ is the current time.

To close out the question, I am looking for a way to **use my approximate values for the pathlines to plot my streaklines from $0<t<2$ s.**

**EDIT:**

It has just occurred to me that in the first of the previous links, an ODE that defines a streakline is mentioned. The ODE is from [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Streamlines,_streaklines,_and_pathlines) and is given here. $$\left\{\begin{matrix}
\frac{d\vec{x}_{str}}{dt}=\vec{u}_P(\vec{x}_{str},t) \\
\vec{x}_{str}(t=\tau_P)=\vec{x}_{P0}
\end{matrix}\right.$$ From Wikipedia...

> $\vec{u}_P(\vec{x},t)$ is the velocity of a particle $P$ at location $\vec{x}$ and time $t$. The parameter $\tau_P$, parameterizes the streakline $\vec{x}_{str}(t,\tau_P)$ and $t_0\le\tau_P\le t$, where $t$ is a time of interest.

The second link from above describes this parameterization, but I am struggling to understand how to work it out in general, not just for this velocity field. But if I can make that work then the ODE should be able to be solved numerically with a similar Runge-Kutta method. However, this [link](https://csmbrannon.net/2015/03/02/streamlines-streaklines-pathlines-and-gridlines/#:%7E:text=The%20equation%20for%20the%20streak%20line%20is%20therefore,%20%5BTau%5D%20x2%20%3D%201%2F3%20t%20%28t-%20%5BTau%5D%29%5E2) suggests that there are errors in the Wikipedia article.

The parameterized ODEs from $0<\tau<t$ should be the following.$$\frac{dx_\tau}{d\theta}=0.5+0.8x_\tau(\theta)$$ $$\frac{dy_\tau}{d\theta}=1.5+2.5\sin\left(\omega(\tau+\theta)\right)-0.8y_\tau(\theta)$$

**Getting some help setting up the numerical integration is where I'm stuck. I'm unsure how to deal with the $\tau$ and $\theta$ terms; i.e, which term is marching forward and what values to put in for $\tau$.**